# Searching Doc and Docx File in subfolders

Tags: batch-file

I want to search and store the doc and docx file path to the variables. Below mentioned "BaseDir=%p%" in p variable contains the path "X:\NEW-ENDORSEMENTS\Backlog_checked\cne\CLIENT-SUPPLIED\Backlog Transfer\Non EV articles\cne24314\Input_Files". In this the path contain a doc and docx files in sub-folders.

When i run the below code, the error message is shown "FINDSTR is not recognizable". Kindly check and clear.

```
set "BaseDir=%p%"

For /f "delims=" %%A in ('
  Dir /B/S/A-D "%BaseDir%\*.doc" ^| Findstr /I "\\doc\\[^\\]*\.doc$"
') Do set doc_path="%%A"

for /f "tokens=*" %%b in ("%doc_path%") do (set doc="%%~dpb")

set BaseDir=%p%

For /f "delims=" %%A in ('
  Dir /B/S/A-D "%BaseDir%\*.docx" ^| Findstr /I "\\doc\\[^\\]*\.docx$"
') Do set docx_path="%%A"

for /f "tokens=*" %%b in ("%docx_path%") do (set docx="%%~dpb")

echo %docx%
echo %doc%
```

Comment: Are you searching for any doc and docx file? Or do they contain specific text in the name?

Comment: yes sir, i m searching doc and docx files in sub-folders. The filenames are in different name, so i m search for *.doc and *.docx method. please help.

Comment: Can the `.doc` and `.docx` files be in more than one of the sub-directories? If so, are you expecting the two variables to contain all of the paths to the sub-directories or only a specific one?

Answer (score 0):

Why so many for loops? Why the need of findstr if you want the path to any doc or docx file?

```
For /f "delims=" %%A in ('Dir /B/S/A-D "%BaseDir%\*.doc*"') Do (
If "%%~xA"==".doc" echo %%~xA path "%%~dpA"
If "%%~xA"==".docx" echo %%~xA path "%%~dpA"
)
```

If you still want to set them as variables, you need delayedexpansion for setting variables in the parenthesized loop.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case there may be more than one subdirectory containing `.doc` and `.docx` files, the following example, may propagate the variables, `%$.doc%` and `%$.docx%`, with all of them:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "BaseDir=X:\NEW-ENDORSEMENTS\Backlog_checked\cne\CLIENT-SUPPLIED\Backlog Transfer\Non EV articles\cne24314\Input_Files"
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Where /R "%BaseDir%" *.doc *.docx 2^>Nul'
) Do If "!$%%~xA!"=="" (Set "$%%~xA=%%~dpA/") Else (
    If "!$%%~xA:%%~dpA/=!"=="!$%%~xA!" Set "$%%~xA=!$%%~xA! "%%~dpA/"
)
For %%A In ($.doc $.docx) Do If Not "!%%A!"=="" Set "%%A="!%%A:\/="!"
Set $.doc 2>Nul
Pause
```

The last two lines are included just to show you the variables with their content, and can be substituted with your own commands as necessary.
*This script has limitations, the main ones being it will not function in Operating Systems pre-Vista, it does not expect directory paths which contain **`!`** characters and due to the length of your base directory path, the size of the variable environment may be exceeded.*